# How to print Even Number after 4 Odd Number with C++

Tags: c++

I use this script to print odd number from 1 to 30.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int  main( )   {
    int  i  =  1 ;
    
    // whele loop from 1 to 30
    while (i  <= 30)  {
        cout << i<< " , ";
        i = i + 2;
    }
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

So the output Will be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29

What i must to do if i want to add Even number after 4 Odd numbers. The output Will be like 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30.

I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thank you

Comment: So are you able to recognize the pattern, what must be added after every fourth and fifth iteration in the loop?

Comment: Use `for` loop, compare whether even or odd and add a counter.

Comment: C++ is not a _scripting_ language BTW.

Comment: `i += "\1\2\1\2\1\2\1\3\2\1"[i%10];`

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration you print a number as you are doing now, however, every 5th iterations **what you do is a bit different**. This is a **condition** you need to test in each iteration: *if true, print like this, if false, print like that*.

Start with the loop as you did. Since you using a counting variable that you always increment, a `for` loop seems more natural than a `while`.

```cpp
int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i += 2) {
        cout << i << " , ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now you add the condition test. For that, you can introduce another variable (`numOddNumbers`) to keep track of how many odd numbers you have printed.

```cpp
int main() {
    int numOddNumbers = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i += 2) {
        if(numOddNumbers > 0 && numOddNumbers % 4 == 0) {
            cout << i + 1 << " , ";
            numOddNumbers = 0;
        } else {
            cout << i << " , ";
            numOddNumbers++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the condition we can use `numOddNumbers % 4 == 0` to check that `numOddNumbers` is amultiple of 4, but since we do not want the condition to be true when `numOddNumbers == 0` we also make sure that `numOddNumbers > 0`.

Notice that differently from `i`, the `numOddNumbers` variable is only incremented when the condition is false, since that is when we print an odd number.

This code will print

```
1 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 10 , 11 , 13 , 15 , 17 , 20 , 21 , 23 , 25 , 27 , 30 ,
```

**Note**: An interesting exercise for you is to simplify this code to use just the counting variable, without the extra `numOddNumbers` variables. The pattern is well defined and you know that the difference is in every 5th itertion.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void showContentVector(vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void oddEvenNumbers(int start, int stop, int quantity, vector<int>& input)
{
    if(start>stop)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(start%2!=0)
    {
        input.push_back(start);
        ++quantity;
    }
    if(quantity==4)
    {
        start+=3;
        input.push_back(start);
        quantity=0;
    }
    oddEvenNumbers(start+1, stop, quantity, input);
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    vector<int> inputVector;
    oddEvenNumbers(0, 30, 0, inputVector);
    cout<<"inputVector <- ";
    showContentVector(inputVector);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
inputVector <- 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30,
```

If you will need an explanation of the solution, write the corresponding comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  int i = 1;
  int step = 1;

  while (i <= 30) {
    if (step % 5 == 0) {
        cout << (i + 1) << ",";
    }else{
        cout << i << ",";
    }
    i += 2;
    step++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).